# ionic date time add 30 minute from min and minus 30 minute from max

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I trying to implement ionic date time picker with min and max. If min it will add 30 minute and if max it will minus 30 minute. what should I do to implement it.. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-ionic-limit-range-ion-datetime-ed2tsd)

HTML

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Start Time</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" min="01:00" max="10:00" pickerFormat="h mm A" minuteValues="0,30"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: if min What? Can you explain more what are you trying?

Comment: I wan..let say.. min start with 01:00 it become 1:30 it should add 30 minute from min time

Comment: it cannot select time 1:00.. It only can select 1:30

Comment: yup it like @javiens said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you simply change your min and max like this?

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" min="01:30" max="09:30" pickerFormat="h mm A" minuteValues="0,30"></ion-datetime>
```

-- **Edit** (based on comments) --

You can modify the min, max parameters for ion-datetime before passing them to your html. See the code below. I am using moment to add/subtract 30 mins to/from the time received from backend. Then using these variables in html

```
import moment from 'moment';

export class HomePage {
  newMin: string;
  newMax: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    const min = "01:00"; // Receive from backend
    const max = "10:00"; // Receive from backend
    this.newMin = moment(min, "HH:mm").add(30, 'minutes').format('HH:mm'); // Add 30 mins
    this.newMax = moment(max, "HH:mm").subtract(30, 'minutes').format('HH:mm') // Subtract 30 mins
  }

}
```

Use these in the html now

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" [min]="newMin" [max]="newMax" pickerFormat="h mm A" minuteValues="0,30"></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: No. I don't want like this because min and max come from backend

Comment: I've modified my answer to handle this.